# MSBuild: Can't copy a dll file to a temp folder

Tags: msbuild

The following msbuild script isn't copying `Com.Library.Shared.dll`  to `c:\tmp\`. Why?

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <DllFiles>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\bin\Debug\Com.Library.Shared.dll</DllFiles>
</PropertyGroup>  
<Target Name="AfterBuild">   
        <Copy 
        SourceFiles="@(DllFiles)" 
        DestinationFiles="@(DllFiles->'c:\tmp\%(Filename)%(Extension)')" /> 
</Target>
```

Comment: Run with verbosity cranked up. And/or add Message statements to see what you are doing. In fact most basic problems like this can always be solved that way. Apart from that: DllFiles is a Property but you are using Item syntax.. Are you sure that works?

Comment: It can't work. needs to be an item, the copy task invocation is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The item access syntax `@()` and `%()` is only available for items, not for properties.

If you change your `PropertyGroup` to an `ItemGroup`, your target should work:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <DllFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\bin\Debug\Com.Library.Shared.dll" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Full example to test outside of the context of a csproj/vbproj file:

```
<Project DefaultTarget="Build">
  <Target Name="Build">
    <ItemGroup>
       <DllFiles Include="test.file" />
    </ItemGroup>  
        <Copy 
        SourceFiles="@(DllFiles)" 
        DestinationFiles="@(DllFiles->'c:\tmp\%(Filename)%(Extension)')" /> 
  </Target>
</Project>
```